# Spring WebClient convert to object with a constructor

Tags: spring-webclient

I know that I can map an object to a body by passing a class to `bodyToMono()`, like this

```
    WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> headersSpec =
            bodySpec.body(Mono.just(myRequest), MyRequest.class);
    MyResponse test = headersSpec.exchangeToMono(s -> {
        if (s.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
            return s.bodyToMono(MyResponse.class);
        } else {
            return s.createException().flatMap(Mono::error);
        }
    }).block();
```

But for it to work I need a no-arg constructor and setters and I don't want setters, but only getters.

My question:

is there any way to make an object from a response by passing a constructor
something like this

```
return s.bodyToMono(new MyResponse(val1, val2, val3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that it is possible if you add

`@JsonProperty("property_name")` to your constructor parameters

Update

So let's say I have this code excerpt

```
MyDto myDto = headersSpec.exchangeToMono(s -> {
    if (s.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
           return s.bodyToMono(MyDto.class);
    } 
    
    <...>
    })
```

MyDto.java looks like this

```
public class MyDto implements Serializable {
    private final String val1;
    private final Val2 val2;
    private final boolean val3;
    private final Integer val4;

    public MyDto(@JsonProperty("val1") String val1,
                       @JsonProperty("val2") val12 val2,
                       @JsonProperty("val3") boolean val3,
                       @JsonProperty("val4") Integer val4) {
        this.val1 = val1;
        this.val2 = val2;
        this.val3 = val3;
        this.val4 = val4;
    }
    
    <...getters...>
    <... no setters...>
    
}
```

So, i.e., val1 from a response is mapped to a val1 (in constructor) by adding a @JsonProperty("val1") next to a val1

Comment: could you please elaborate how that works